# Sencha Touch 2 LocalStorageProxy dosn't save data to LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, touch, local-storage

i'm trying to save some app settings to the LocalStorage.
I have a model with the LocalStorageProxy, I have a Store with the model and autoload = true.
I sync the store after adding a record.
The corresponding Docs: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage
But after reloading the app in the browser (Chrome) the data are lost. Addidionally to the autoload flag i do a manual store.load() in the launch method of the application.
All is working fine until i reload the app.
Any ideas on that? Thanks!

the model:

```
Ext.define('LwvMediaReminder.model.Setting', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Field',
        'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'
    ],


    config: {
    idProperty: 'settingsId',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'settingsId',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'bPush',
            type: 'boolean'
        },
        {
            name: 'bEmail',
            type: 'boolean'
        },
        {
            name: 'sEmail',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'sToken',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'settings'
    }
}
});
```

the store

```
Ext.define('LwvMediaReminder.store.SettingsStore', {

extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.SettingsStore',


requires: [
    'LwvMediaReminder.model.Setting'
],


config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'LwvMediaReminder.model.Setting',
    storeId: 'SettingsStore'
}
});
```

the method in my SettingsController that should save the settings object, i always use only one record with the id 0:

```
onSaveSettingsButtonTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {        var mainView = this.getMainView(),
        store = Ext.getStore('SettingsStore'),
        properties = {
            settingsId: 0,
            bPush:  this.getPushCheckbox().isChecked(),
            bEmail: this.getEmailCheckbox().isChecked(),
            sEmail: this.getEmailField().getValue(),
            sToken: this.getTokenField().getValue()
        },
        record = store.getById(0),
        save = true;

    // some form validation
    if (properties.bEmail) {
        if (properties.sEmail === '') {
            save = false;
            Ext.Msg.alert('Fehler', 'Bitte geben sie auch eine gültige Email-Adresse an.');
        }
        if (!this.validateEmail(properties.sEmail)) {
            save = false;
            Ext.Msg.alert('Fehler', 'Die angegebene Email-Adresse ist nicht gültig.');
        }
    }

    // save the record
    if (save) {
        if (null !== record) {
            record.set(properties);
        } else {
            store.add(properties);
        }
        store.sync();
        mainView.pop();
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the solution.
It seems that the LocalstorageProxy has problems with given object ids.
I was setting the Object Id to 0 by default because i wanted only one object at a time with all my settings in one object.
Unfortunatly the local-storage wasn't able to write it to the browser storage.
No I have rewritten the code so that sencha can set the Id by itself. Now it seems to works fine.
And i can access the record by calling the .first() function from the store.

new code snippet:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('SettingsStore'),
// no preset id anymore
properties = {
    bPush:  this.getPushCheckbox().isChecked(),
    bEmail: this.getEmailCheckbox().isChecked(),
    sEmail: this.getEmailField().getValue(),
    sToken: this.getTokenField().getValue()
},
// reading the first entry because there is always only one in my app
record = store.first();
```

I hope that will help somebody in the future.